# Simulating integer overflow in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, integer-overflow

Python 2 has two integer datatypes `int` and `long`, and automatically converts between them as necessary, especially in order to avoid integer overflow.

I am simulating a C function in Python and am wondering if there are standard ways to re-enable integer overflow. For the nonce, I've used

```
overflow_point = maxint + 1
if value > overflow_point:
    value -= 2 * overflow_point
```

Is there a more standard way to do the same thing?

Comment: You could create your own number data type (class) that defines how addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division are performed.

Comment: What is your aim with this? Modulo-semantics or C-semantics including undefined behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the basic idea is sound, but needs some tweaks:

1. your function doesn't overflow on `sys.maxint+1`, but it should;
2. `sys.maxint` can be exceeded several times over as a result of a single operation;
3. negative values below `-sys.maxint-1` also need to be considered.

With this in mind, I came up with the following:

```
import sys

def int_overflow(val):
  if not -sys.maxint-1 <= val <= sys.maxint:
    val = (val + (sys.maxint + 1)) % (2 * (sys.maxint + 1)) - sys.maxint - 1
  return val
```

Answer (score 8):

This function should convert your numbers to look like hardware integers. Depending on your application, you might need to apply this function between each stage of your operations.

```
def correct(value, bits, signed):
    base = 1 << bits
    value %= base
    return value - base if signed and value.bit_length() == bits else value
```

The following shortcut functions may come in handy for "casting" values to their appropriate range:

```
byte, sbyte, word, sword, dword, sdword, qword, sqword = (
    lambda v: correct(v, 8, False), lambda v: correct(v, 8, True),
    lambda v: correct(v, 16, False), lambda v: correct(v, 16, True),
    lambda v: correct(v, 32, False), lambda v: correct(v, 32, True),
    lambda v: correct(v, 64, False), lambda v: correct(v, 64, True)
)
```

As an example of how you might use them, a bug can reproduced that one might see in C. If one were to write a for loop using a byte to print out 0 - 255, the loop might never end. The following program demonstrates this problem:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 256:
        print(counter)
        counter = byte(counter + 1)


def correct(value, bits, signed):
    base = 1 << bits
    value %= base
    return value - base if signed and value.bit_length() == bits else value


byte, sbyte, word, sword, dword, sdword, qword, sqword = (
    lambda v: correct(v, 8, False), lambda v: correct(v, 8, True),
    lambda v: correct(v, 16, False), lambda v: correct(v, 16, True),
    lambda v: correct(v, 32, False), lambda v: correct(v, 32, True),
    lambda v: correct(v, 64, False), lambda v: correct(v, 64, True)
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, can you please add a few examples using your functions?

Comment: @GabrielStaples How do you like the example? If you wish to change it or add more, you can edit the answer to improve it.

Answer (score 5):

Does your function use division or right bit-shifting?  If not then you don't
need to worry about overflows at each stage of the calculation because
you will always get the "correct" answer modulo 2^32 or 2^64.  Before
returning the result (or before doing division or right bit-shifting)
you can normalize back to the standard integer range using something
like

```
import sys

HALF_N = sys.maxint + 1
N = HALF_N * 2

def normalize(value):
    return (value + HALF_N) % N - HALF_N
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there's a convenient way to do this natively because it's not normally considered a problem, so it's not something the python devs would want to build in.  I think the way you're doing it is fine.  You could even subclass the `int` built-in type and override the [`__add__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__), `__sub__()`, etc operator methods to include your functionality, but that might be overkill.

Comment: What would overloading `__setattr__` accomplish? You never set attributes on ints.

Comment: Edited to clarify my intention.  The subclass could override __add__() to use the new __sertattr__() functionality, which would set whatever attribute holds the int value.  It's major overkill of course.

Comment: int objects are supposed to be immutable. `__add__` should return a new object not set any attributes.

Comment: Ah, OK, good point.  So maybe it could calculate the overflowed value and return that.  I'll make that change.  Thanks for the feedback, I'm rusty on python reflection :)

Comment: +1 then. Sadly, too much overhead in python to be actually a usable solution.

Comment: Oh for sure.  I love python dearly but it's ever so slow sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

Use NumPy (which is written in C and exposes native machine-level integers). NumPy has these integer types:

Signed integers:

- np.int8
- np.int16
- np.int32

Unsigned integers:

- np.uint8
- np.uint16
- np.uint32

For example (notice it overflows after integer value 127):

```py
import numpy as np

counter = np.int8(0)
one = np.int8(1)

for i in range(130):
    print(type(counter), counter)
    counter = counter + one
```

At any point you can convert back to a Python integer with just `int(counter)`, for example.