# difference between javascript and ruby integers (using left shift bitwise operator)

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm trying to replicate a javascript check digit function in Ruby. The results are differing and it looks as though it is related to the size of the integer.

in Ruby:

`puts "#{1421974191} | #{(1421974191 << 5)}"`

produces `1421974191 | 45503174112`

in javascript:

`alert(1421974191 + ' | ' + (1421974191 << 5))`

produces `1421974191 | -1741466144`

I'd be grateful for any advice on why this is happening, and how I can replicate the javascript in Ruby.

Thanks in advance

Dan

Answer (score 3):

JS' bitwise operators are limited to 32-bit values, so you're getting an overflow. From [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.

Modern JS engines will actually prefer the two's complement format and bail out to a 64-bit floating point value if you push them, but the bitwise operators force a conversion back to 32-bit integers before doing anything.

The spec is very clear about this. From [section 12.8.3.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-shift-operator):

> 12. Return the result of left shifting lnum by shiftCount bits. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

To mimic integer overflow in Ruby (or any language with large numbers), you can use the formula (taken from [this Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771499/129032)):

```
((n + 2147483647) % 4294967294) - 2147483647
```

As the answer notes, this only works with left-shifting, not division or right-shifting.

Comment: thanks @ssube, it was looking like a js limitation, any ideas on replicating this in Ruby?

Comment: @d_a_n I've never heard of anybody wanting to force overflows, but it's pretty easy math. Editing it in.